# Do polynomials $a(x), b(x) \in R[x]$ and $c(y), d(y) \in R[y]$ exist such that $1+xy+x^2 y^2 = a(x)c(y) + b(x)d(y)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

The following is a homework question, I'm just looking for guidance as to what I can do to approach the question (it isn't for any credit, but homework nonetheless). I am stumped on how to approach it. Any tips or hints would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

> Do polynomials $a(x), b(x) \in R[x]$ and $c(y), d(y) \in R[y]$ exist such that $$1+xy+x^2 y^2 = a(x)c(y) + b(x)d(y)$$

Comment: Anything known about $R$? I would probably assume it is commutative...?

Comment: Let $f(x,y):=a(x)c(y)+b(x)d(y),\;$ and $\;(A_{i,j})_{i,j=1,2,3}\;$ be a matrix where $\;A_{i,j}:=f(x_i,y_j)\;$ for any distinct $x_i$ and $y_j$. What is the determinant of $A$?

Comment: @user357980 Just properties of real numbers, nothing too special (that I can think of).

Comment: @Somos I thought of that path, but unfortunately we don't "know" about determinants yet :/

Comment: Try $\;f(x,y):=a(x)c(y)\;$ first. Can you see that $\;f(x_1,y_1)f(x_2,y_2)=f(x_1,y_2)f(x_2,y_1)\;$ and that this can not happen for $\;f(x,y)=1+xy+x^2y^2?$

Answer (score 0):

No. There are no such polynomials.

Note that $ 0 \neq \frac{3}{4} + \left( xy + \frac{1}{2} \right)^{2} =  1+ xy + x^{2}y^{2}  = \det A (x, y)$, where $A(x, y) = \begin{pmatrix}a(x) & -d(y) \\ b(x)  & c(y)  \\  \end{pmatrix} $

This means that the columns of $A(x, y)$ are linearly independent for all $x$ and for all $y$.

If you now suppose such polynomials exist, then plugging in $y = 0$ and then again by plugging in $x = 0$ into the original equation, we see that $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ cannot have a common root as that leads to 1 =0. Similarly, for $c(y)$ and $d(y)$. Suppose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of $b(x)$ and $c(y)$ respectively, then $\det A (\alpha, \beta) =0$, which is a contradiction.